# i want to set in my entity about minimum value is 1 and maximum value is 999 how to set that?

Tags: java, entity

have try to set in my entity with not null, this code is okay

```
@NotNull(message = "Minimum Day can't be null")
private Integer minimumDay;

@NotNull(message = "Maximum Day can't be null")
private Integer maximumDay;
```

but i want to know how to set in entity about if i need to set minimumDay = 1 and maximum day = 999

how to set like that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Hibernate, check this post: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-validate-entity-attribute-value-within-defined-range/ from Thorben Janssen should solve your doubt.

You can do whit hibernate-validator

"When you now try to persist a Book entity and the value of numPages is outside of the allowed range, Hibernate Validator throws one of the following exceptions"

```
@Entity
public class Book {
 
    @Min(100)
    @Max(1000)
    private int numPages;
 
    …
}
```